# Get filter options from SQL table having master data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table with 50-60 columns having master data,something like below (just example).

[image]

I need to show filters to allow the customer to filter the data. So the result would be something like below, which I will bind to drop-downs on web page.

[image]

So, I though of having a FilterOptions table which tells me which column to look for which drop-down filter, something like:

[image]

Now, I am not able to figure out sql query I need to get data out in format as in second image. Probably need to pivot MasterData table and join with FilterOptions, but how, not sure.
Any help/pointer is appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `apply`:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (values ('Country', t.countryCode, t.countryName),
             ('Country', t.StateCode, t.StatueName),
             ('City', t.CityCode, t.CityName),

     ) v(label, key, value);
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try it out and get back to you. The number of columns are large (50-60), any view on how to make it easier ?

Comment: @MilindThakkar . . . You can generate the code dynamically -- either explicitly as dynamic SQL or manually by getting the columns and generating it in a spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks once again. I will have to take dynamic sql route..Any help/pointer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unpivot` like below:

```
declare @master table(id int, countrycode varchar(10), countryname varchar(20), statecode varchar(10), statename varchar(20), citycode varchar(10), cityname varchar(20))
insert into @master
select 1, 'IN', 'INDIA', 'MH', 'Maharashtra', 'PNE', 'Pune'
union
select 2, 'US', 'USA', 'PA', 'Pennsylvania', 'PH', 'Philadelphia'
union
select 3, 'US', 'USA', 'NY', 'NewYork', 'NY', 'NewYork'
union
select 4, 'US', 'USA', 'NY', 'Pennsylvania', 'PT', 'NewYork'

declare @filters table (label varchar(20), [key] varchar(10), [value] varchar(20))
insert into @filters
select 'Country', 'IN', 'India'
union
select 'Country', 'US', 'USA'
union
select 'State', 'MH', 'MH'
union
select 'State', 'PA', 'Pennsylvania'
union
select 'City', 'NY', 'NewYork'
union
select 'City', 'PNE', 'Pune'

select id,cc countrycode, ccval, cn countryname, cnval, sc statecode, scval, sn statename, snval, cic citycode, cival, cin cityname, cinval
into #temp
from
(
    select id, countrycode, countryname, statecode, statename, citycode, cityname
    from @master
)t
unpivot
(
    cc for ccval in (countrycode)
)upvtcountry
unpivot
(
    cn for cnval in (countryname)
)upvtcountryname
unpivot
(
    sc for scval in (statecode)
)upvtstate
unpivot
(
    sn for snval in (statename)
)upvtstatename
unpivot
(
    cic for cival in (citycode)
)upvtcity
unpivot
(
    cin for cinval in (cityname)
)upvtcityname

select distinct f.label, case f.label when 'City' then t.cival when 'Country' then t.ccval when 'State' then t.scval end keycolumnname
                     ,case f.label when 'City' then t.cinval when 'Country' then t.cnval when 'State' then t.snval end valucolumnname
from #temp t
left join @filters f
on f.[key] = case f.label when 'City' then t.citycode when 'Country' then t.countrycode when 'State' then t.statecode end

drop table #temp
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try it out and get back to you. The number of columns are large (50-60), any view on how to make it easier ?